# Is there any particular reason why Haran (חָרָן) is spelled as חָרָנָה in B'resheith 27:43 & 28:10?

Tags: hebrew, vayeitzei, spelling-variants

Going through this week's Parsha (Vayetze), I came across these specific verses and was confused about why the ה is attached to חָרָן.  Does anyone know why and are there any references for such?  Todah Rabbah.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a common suffix known in Biblical Hebrew as the 'locative hei' or the 'directional hei' in that by placing it at the end of the said place/location it transforms the meaning to "to that place". So חרנה means "to Charan" i.e. that he went towards Charan.

It works with common nouns, proper nouns and directional adverbs.

So for example:

**Common Nouns** -
ההר (mountain) becomes הָהָ֑רָה (see [Devarim 10:1](https://www.sefaria.org/Deuteronomy.10.1?lang=bi&aliyot=0)),
ארץ (ground / earth) becomes אָֽרְצָה (see [Shmuel II 14:11](https://www.sefaria.org/II_Samuel.14.11?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))

**Proper Nouns** -
מצרים (Egypt) becomes מִצְרַ֔יְמָה (see [Bereishis 41:57](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.41.57?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)),
בבל (Babylonia) becomes בָּבֶֽלָה (see [Yirmiyahu 29:20](https://www.sefaria.org/Jeremiah.29.20?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=he))

**Directional Adverbs** -
שם (there) becomes שָֽׁמָּה (see [Bereishis 24:8](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.24.8?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en))
צפון (north) becomes צָפֹ֥נָה (see [Bereishis 13:14](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.13.14?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en)) - the other directions are mentioned there in the pasuk.

As far as scriptural support alluding to this grammatical rule, it is worth noting the pasuk in [Bereishis 14:10](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.14.10?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en) where it writes:

> וְעֵ֣מֶק הַשִׂדִּ֗ים בֶּֽאֱרֹ֤ת בֶּאֱרֹת֙ חֵמָ֔ר וַיָּנֻ֛סוּ מֶֽלֶךְ־סְדֹ֥ם וַעֲמֹרָ֖ה וַיִּפְּלוּ־שָׁ֑מָּה וְהַנִּשְׁאָרִ֖ים **הֶ֥רָה** נָּֽסוּ׃
>
> Now the Valley of Siddim was dotted with bitumen pits; and the kings of Sodom and Gomorrah, in their flight, threw themselves into them, while the rest escaped **to the hill country**. (Sefaria translation)

[Rashi](https://www.sefaria.org/Genesis.14.10?lang=bi&aliyot=0&p2=Rashi_on_Genesis.14.10.2&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) over there writes as follows:

> הרה נסו means THEY FLED TO A MOUNTAIN. **The word הרה is the same as לְהַר. When a word requires a ל as a prefix one may put instead a ה as a suffix**...

Answer (score 8):

The Talmud (Yevamot 13b) states:

> ובית הלל
> כיון דכתיב חוצה כמאן דכתיב לחוץ דמי דתניא ר׳ נחמיה אומר כל תיבה שצריכה למ״ד בתחלתה  הטיל לה הכתוב ה״א בסופה ותנא דבי
> ר׳ ישמעאל כגון אלים אלימה מחנים מחנימה מצרים מצרימה
> דבלתימה ירושלימה מדברה
>
> And Beth Hillel? — Since the expression used was huzah it is just the same as if la-huz had been written; as it was taught: R. Nehemiah said, ‘In the case of every word which requires a ‘lamed’ at the beginning Scripture has placed a ‘he’ at the end; and at the School of R. Ishmael the following examples were given: Elim, Elimah; Mahanayim, Mahanayimah; Mizrayim, Mizraimah; Dibelathaimah; Yerushalaimah; midbarah.
>
> (Soncino translation)

Thus “Charanah” חרנה is the equivalent of “lecharan” לחרן, meaning “to Charan”.

Comment: Does this answer why it's spelled this way in these instances? This just explains the grammar is good.

Comment: @robev i believe it does actually sound better grammatically

Comment: @larry909 what do you mean sounds better? Rolls off the tongue?

Comment: I agree with @robev. It doesn't answer the question.

Answer (score 0):

Alex's answer above explains how such a word usage is allowed to be used in this instance. But why *would* it be used in this instance?

As rashi and sifsei chachamin state in 28:10, he was going **towards** Charan, not **to** Charan. He stopped for 14 years to study by the school of Shem and Evar and only then actually went to Charan. The point being, that he is on a Journey, with the end destination being Charon. As opposed to going directly to Charan. Possibly similar in style and usage to the word קדימה: Going forward, or eastward.

Comment: What's the difference in English between to and towards? How do you know חרנה is towards and לחרן is to, and connotes the same difference in biblical Hebrew as you assume exists in English? A source for your assertions would make this a complete answer.

Comment: @robev i edited the answer. (Did you see the sources i quoted? To me it seems that this is what they are trying to say.)

Comment: What does the suffix have to do with not arriving at the destination? When it says ויבאו אלימה had they not arrived yet? Where did rivkah stop on the way when yitzchak took her האהלה שרה אמו?

Comment: @DoubleAA Possibly similar in style and usage to the word קדימה: Going forward, or eastward

Comment: @DoubleAA I'm only speaking about this case.

Comment: @DoubleAA not every case of a suffix means the same thing. It is one way to explain the word that has a suffix. But it doesn't apply to every single case.

Comment: They are explaining that Ya'akov actually didn't go to Charan, but went elsewhere first. This insight isn't from the grammatical formulation of חרנה, but from other rationales.

Comment: @robev right. But in such a case the word usage in the verse fits correctly, and is a better way to use then with ל

Comment: You haven't shown that one grammatical usage is more suitable for one syntactical usage.

Comment: @DoubleAA if it would have said לחרן that would be incorrect, as he did not go to Charan. He went to Shem and Evar's study hall.

Comment: If חרנה means the same as לחרן then you have the same question on the verse as you have to DoubleAA...who says the answer is חרנה means he didn't actually go there first. If anything your sources disprove you as they could simply justify their explanation from the grammar. Instead it's a whole math calculation.

Comment: @robev in לשון קודש, a word or word construct can have vague and multiple meanings. Not so like in other languages where a word is usually is very specific and means one thing only

Comment: Even if that's true it's not up to you or me to decide what it means.

Comment: @robev a word with a ה at the end can have a few ways of explaining it's meaning

Comment: @robev i believe it is. It is part of Torah study. And rashi, sifsei chachamin, and the narrative itself lends support to this interpretation

Comment: Out of the two responses I have seen thus far recorded as answers, I prefer yours more. However, it doesn't really answer the question. Toddah Rabbah for your response.